# Change event doesn't work, but Onkeyup works as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code

```
$(".steps").on("keyup", "input", function() {
    console.log('test');
} );
```

This works fine. I get `test` logged each time button is released. But when I change this event to `change` it just doesn't fire.

```
$(".steps").on("change", "input", function() {
    console.log('test');
} );
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: `change` will only fire when the `input` element has lost focus.

Comment: Your question is totally legit. 
That the change method requires to lose change aswell is an iIIogical abomination why not call the trigger "focus" then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**oninput(modern browsers,IE9+):** triggers when text is changed in the input (can see change in the textbox).

**onchange:** triggers when text has changes AND the element loses focus.

**onpropertychange(IE less than 9 ):** similar to oninput (doesnt seem to capture everything, deleting doesn't always fire)

This is what i use to capture events immediately(capture input, propertychange, and paste):

```
$('input').on('input propertychange paste', function (e) {

});
```

Answer (score 1):

A change event will fire when the input has changed AND loses focus. Or when you call .change() on the element.